# Show only certain parts of a web page in a web view, AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

How can I get the certain parts from Website and show in WebView, Android Studio???

Below Image is that I want get part (square in red part)
[image]

and site is this : https://kimpga.com

I'd like to display only the red part as an Android web view. What should I do?

and then I used this method: `webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('').style.display='none'");`

but that website doesn't have div id and doesn't work method!

+) add homepage source

Please understand to attach the overall picture. I'd like to show you the part of div selected in blue through a web view.

[image]

Comment: Well what does it have that you can parse it out? Tell how the html source is build up please.

Comment: Please understand that I am attaching the overall picture because it is difficult to express the structure. I'd like to show you the part of div selected in blue through a web view. @blackapps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it!

using

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url)
        {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "document.getElementsByClassName(//classname//)[index of document].style.display='none'; " +
                    "})()");
        }
    });
```